# how to implement and get object value of flexsheet using Javascript in .NET MVC Application

Tags: .net

I want to use flexsheet controls for sheet like excel sheet for my .NET MVC application. For that i have successfully bind the flexsheet data and now i want get that object data can anyone please help me how to find and get object value of flexsheet using javascript.